# choosing right type of batch job

Tags: oracle, jobs, job-scheduling

We are trying to copy part of our data from one Oracle database to another. We might need to do same job several time after a while (dependent on how fast the copied data is used).
We need to look at 4 tables and transfer the data and the relationship between these tables based on the Status (for example get all customer and their orders where the customer status is initiated).

These are requirements:

1. Bring 1000 line of data (based on status)
2. The structure of data in target db is not similar to the original db
3. The status of copied data to the target tabels will be changing. When only 50 rows are left and their status has not been changed, the batch job must run again and bring another 1000 rows.

What kind of technology and batch type should we use? appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

oracle has its own Job/Task Scheduler. You can create Job and attach your Stored Procedure to it.

The Task can also send you email upon completion with cempletion status.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'update_sales',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY',
   start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  '20-NOV-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

For Email notifications

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION (
  job_name   =>  'EOD_JOB',
  recipients =>  'jsmith@example.com, rjones@example.com',
  sender     =>  'do_not_reply@example.com',
  subject    =>  'Scheduler Job Notification-%job_owner%.%job_name%-%event_type%',
  body       =>   '%event_type% occurred at %event_timestamp%. %error_message%',
  events     =>  'JOB_FAILED, JOB_BROKEN, JOB_DISABLED, JOB_SCH_LIM_REACHED');
END;
/
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034)

If the tables are huge, you can consider to export import by `expdp/impdp`. But the decision is really depends on your data size, fail tolerance, complexity of the data, difference between source and destination table structure and so forth

If your intention is to feed your target table on real-time and you don't want to make investment on any technology. I can advice you to connect your target db with `Database Link` and create trigger on your source table so that whenever INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE occurs you can insert into your target table via DB Link.

Comment: What about as I wrote, we need to run the job when the copied data is consumed. so we don't know when we would execute the second (or other) times?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very open ended question and the answer really depends on what type of data you're moving, how much data you plan to move, any technical/business/legal requirements for moving the data (e.g. if there is sensitive/confidential data, you do not want to be creating plaintext .csv files for moving the data,) whether or not you need to store the exported data for any length of time, etc.

If you are moving data from one Oracle database to another, you might want to start with looking at [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A.htm#SUTIL2877). Data Pump is a utility that's used for "very high-speed movement of data and metadata from one database to another." Using Data Pump, you could easily use cron and some simple scripting to schedule an automated export and import of the relevant table data. Since you mentioned that the data should be transferred based on `Status`, you can use a query in your Data Pump command to only export the rows that meet your criteria like so:

```
expdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=expdp_full.log query='[YOURSCHEMA].[YOURTABLE1]:"WHERE Status=X",[YOURSCHEMA].[YOURTABLE2]:"WHERE status=X"'
```

Data Pump can also be used to transform the data when it's exported/imported, such as through remapping schemas/tablespaces and executing SQL on rows that meet certain conditions. Data Pump is a powerful utility with many options, so make sure to research what the utility can do because it may come in handy, even if you don't decide on Data Pump for this specific activity.

Depending on your licensing situation, you could also use something like [GoldenGate](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWUAD/wu_about_gg.htm#GWUAD110) to replicate the relevant data to another database of your choosing, but that may be overkill for what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: thanks,the job is not exactly scheduling job, it will re-execut based on how many rows of data in the target db is consumed. please se my updates-

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure if I understand the 3rd requirement - "The copied data is consumed (status changed). When 50 line of data is left (status is not changed in target db) the job must be executed again and bring 1000 more lines."

Does this mean that when there are 50 rows of data in one table, the job needs to be executed again? Can you give a more detailed explanation of that requirement? I don't understand what the requirement is and I'm not sure how to advise on it.

Comment: An example is like you first run the job and copy 1000 line and move them to two tables in the target database (db2). The clients are using these data and make an order which changes the status of the data (in target db). When only 50 (or less than 50) line are left (they are not ordered), the job must be run again and bring 1000 more from db1 to db2.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want for the job to be ran once from the Source DB (db1) to transform and import data into the Target DB (db2.) From then on, you want the job to be ran automatically based on the number of rows in a specific table within the Target DB? So, Step 1: Run job from Source (db1) Step 2. Transform and import data, Step 3. Run job whenever number of rows is less than 50 in Target (db2), correct? You could accomplish that with a trigger that runs whenever the Target table is less than 50 rows, but that will not be efficient.

Comment: That requirement is a little odd, and it's probably better to do this type of operation on a set schedule rather than based on an arbitrary number of rows in a specific table. What if someone truncates the table by accident and the job is kicked off unexpectedly? Will your data be recoverable? If the number of rows (50) has a specific purpose then by all means, but I would revisit that requirement for additional clarification. Why 50 rows? Why not schedule this on a nightly or weekly basis?